# Custom Cache per Country - Wordpress php [Disable Cache from function]

Tags: php, css, wordpress, caching

On our website at [www.EllasBubbles.com](http://www.EllasBubbles.com), we are using a functions.php script to execute an alternative stylesheet to users who are outside of U.S/Canada. This script is as follows:

```
  // [International] - Dark Mode
 add_action( 'wp_head' , 'custom_inline_css', 200 );
function custom_inline_css() {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Geolocation object class
    $geolocation_instance = new WC_Geolocation();
    // Get user IP 
    $user_ip_address = $geolocation_instance->get_ip_address();
    // Get geolocated user IP country code.
    $user_geolocation = $geolocation_instance->geolocate_ip( $user_ip_address );

    // For all countries except 'US'
    if($user_geolocation['country'] !== 'US' && $user_geolocation['country'] !== 'CA'){
        
        ?>
<style>
<?php include 'international.php'; ?>
</style>
<?php
}
}
```

We use cloud flare to manage our Cache. I have properly setup bypass rules for these two files:

```
ellasbubbles.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/international.php
ellasbubbles.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/flatsome.css
```

When loading the site from an international VPN, the "Dark Mode" (Outside U.S/Canada) version is displayed. However, when disabling the VPN; we are stuck on Dark Mode. Which is a bypassed file with Cloudflare Cache - and simply makes no sense to me.

This leads me to believe that the instance of the WC_Geolocation class is being cached somewhere on the Wordpress website. I have searched everywhere for a solution, and can not determine the best way to perform this custom CSS per country. Can we disable caching from function custom_inline_css ? Should I change international.php to css? Is there a better way to go about this?

```
 Update 1: When I disabled caching from the entire website in cloud flare, this works fine!
    Update 2: When I disable caching from everything inside ellasbubbles.com/wp-content/*; this still does not work properly..what file am I missing?
Update 3: I disabled all folders one by one to no avail
```

Please help me help everyone

Comment: Why don't you enqueue the style based on your rules? This way you can add a random version of the end of the file to ensure is not cached (in Cloudflare or in the browser)

Comment: It seems that this function is "holding" the user location. For instance, if I connect to a Spanish VPN, I will see a Spanish Video on the home page; along with the dark mode content. Then when I disconnect from the VPN (back to U.S), I still see that Spanish video on the home page... I am not sure if this solution would work around that?

Comment: I feel that these values or content is being stored elsewhere and there is another file (such as WP-Head or something) that needs to be prevented from caching as well. The reason I am confident on this is because if I disable cache from the entire site at cloud flare.... everything works fine

Comment: I see, then is not a stylesheet issue: "On our website at www.EllasBubbles.com, we are using a functions.php script to execute an alternative stylesheet to users who are outside of U.S/Canada."
If you disable the Cache on Cloud Flare, it works as expected? Did you flush the browser caché?

Comment: Yes, check out Update 2. When I disable caching on all files - everything works as intended. When I disable everything inside assets; this is not working properly. I know what I can do to narrow this down - but wasn't sure if there were quicker suggestions?

Comment: Shot in the dark here, even in dark/incognito mode local storage and temporary cache storage is enable, when you terminate the session everything is flushed out. On my end (from France) everything looks fine.

Comment: I am clearing my cache between each attempt :/ It is likely you tested during bypass all or something (I am in the midst of changes)

Comment: Also quick thought, night mode can be set to follow the default desktop mode, depending on what you're using (I usually do that when I implement a night mode on a website). @ see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: Thank you for the help, but that is not what I am going for here. This is not a "night mode" issue. We have custom CSS throughout the site